# Calculating the following standard normal probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X \sim N (0.5, 0.25)$. Using the output from MatLab below, calculate:
(a) $P(X > 1.5)$;
(b) $P(0 < X < 1.5)$

My calculations:

For (a) I have for the cdf when $P(X > x) = 1-P(X \le x)$ therefore $P(X > 1.5) = 1-P(X\le1.5) = \frac{1.5-0.5}{\sqrt{0.25}}=1-\Phi(2)$

As for (b) I have $\frac{-0.05}{\sqrt{0.25}}<Z<\frac{1.5-0.5}{\sqrt{0.25}}=\Phi(1) - [1-\Phi(2)]$

Have I approached my calculations correctly? I've been slightly thrown off by the inequality signs, so If I've made a mistake I'd appreciate a small detail on the explanation of the inequalities for the cdf, and how different is $P(X \ge x)$ to $P(X > x)$?

Comment: Your answers look correct, though the second would more naturally be $\Phi(2)-\Phi(-1)$. The first could have been $\Phi(-2)$. For a continuous distribution $P(X \ge x)=P(X > x)$ since $P(X = x)=0$

Comment: @Henry Ah yes. The negative 1 slipped my mind for some reason but it's probably how I wrote it out that confused me. Following (at)Sam OT's method should help reduce errors like this in the future for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ and then write $X = Z/2 + 1/2$. This way, $X \sim N(1/2, 1/4)$, as desired.
Now,
$$X \ge 3/2 \iff Z/2 + 1/2 \ge 3/2 \iff Z/2 \ge 1 \iff Z \ge 2.$$
So yes, $\Pr(X \ge 1.5) = \Pr(Z \ge 2) = 1 - \Phi(2).$

You should try to do (b) using this formulation. What you've written currently doesn't make sense. The $=$ signs don't follow. Eg, what does the penultimate $=$ sign mean in "$P(X > 1.5) = 1-P(X\le1.5) = \frac{1.5-0.5}{\sqrt{0.25}}=1-\Phi(2)$"?

Try to use this precise and rigorous formulation with $Z$.

---

Lastly, $\Pr(X \ge x) - \Pr(X > x) = \Pr(X = x)$, but this is $0$ for every $x$! So the two are equal.

Comment: Aha! This makes perfect sense to me. I like the way you write out the formulas, I'll give (b) a go like this - I have $P(0 < X < 1.5) = P(-1 \le Z \le 2) = \Phi(2) - \Phi(-1)$. It's definitely easier on my eyes and to memorise

Comment: Excellent :) -- btw, you shouldn't be trying to memorise _formulas_ like this. Rather, you should remember _ideas/techniques_ which you can use. Converting a non-standard normal $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ into $Y = \sigma Z + \mu$ with $Z \sim N(0,1)$ a standard normal is a useful technique! You can often use this in other places, too, for random variables which have scaling properties. Eg, $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)/\lambda$, ie all the parameter in the exponential distribution does is scale it. Sometimes, writing a binomial as a sum of Bernoullis is helpful, too